# How to input mulitple keys and the output should return multiple values. Please check the script and my comment

Tags: python, dictionary

```
nestdic = { 'modelname' : {
'mod-num-1221' : 'LENEVO' ,
'mod-num-1222' : 'ASUS' ,
'mod-num-1223' : 'APPLE' ,
'mod-num-1224' : 'SAMSUNG' ,
'mod-num-1225' : 'HP'
}, 'ostype' : {
'LENEVO' : 'Windows' ,
'ASUS' : 'Windows' ,
'APPLE' : 'IOS' ,
'SAMSUNG' : 'LINUX' ,
'HP' : 'Windows'
} }

option = input("Please select from the below options\n1. Vendor Name type\n2. OS type\n\n\nPlease make a selection or press Q to quit: ")
if option == '1':
        for i in range(5):
                modelnum = input("Please enter the model num: ")
                model = list(nestdic['modelname'])
                if modelnum not in model:
                        print("Model name not found")
                        continue
                modelname = nestdic['modelname'][modelnum]
                if modelnum in model:
                        print("model name = " + modelname)
elif option == '2':
        for i in range(5):
                compname = input("Please enter the vendors name: ")
                os = list(nestdic['ostype'])
                if compname not in os:
                        print("os name not found")
                        continue
                compsname = nestdic['ostype'][compname]
                if compname in os:
                        print("OS type = " + compsname)
```

When I run this script it asks me options.
If I select model number it ask me to enter the model number...when I enter the model number(Key) it gives me the model name(values)...Currently, I am able to give a single input and getting a single output only. I want to input multiple values and get multiple outputs.
Input = mod-num-1221, mod-num-1222, mod-num-1225
Output = LENEVO , ASUS, HP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to study here. I made several other modifications to your code to correct some inefficiencies; take a look at the comments.

```
import re

nestdic = { 'modelname' : {
'mod-num-1221' : 'LENEVO' ,
'mod-num-1222' : 'ASUS' ,
'mod-num-1223' : 'APPLE' ,
'mod-num-1224' : 'SAMSUNG' ,
'mod-num-1225' : 'HP'
}, 'ostype' : {
'LENEVO' : 'Windows' ,
'ASUS' : 'Windows' ,
'APPLE' : 'IOS' ,
'SAMSUNG' : 'LINUX' ,
'HP' : 'Windows'
} }

option = input("Please select from the below options\n1. Vendor Name type\n2. OS type\n\n\nPlease make a selection or press Q to quit: ")
if option == '1':
        models = nestdic['modelname'] # no reason for this to be in the loop and don't convert to list
        while True: # loop while there is an error
                error = False
                modelnums_str = input("Please enter the model numbers separated by commas: ").strip()
                if modelnums_str == '':
                        continue
                modelnums = [modelnum for modelnum in re.split(r',\s*', modelnums_str)]
                modelnames = []
                for modelnum in modelnums:
                        if modelnum not in models:
                                print(f'Model number {modelnum} not found.')
                                error = True
                        else:
                                modelnames.append(models[modelnum])
                if error:
                        continue
                if modelnames:
                        print(f"Input = {', '.join(modelnums)}, Output = {', '.join(modelnames)}")
                        break

elif option == '2':
        os = nestdic['ostype'] # no reason for this to be in the loop and don't convert to a list
        for i in range(5):
                compname = input("Please enter the vendors name: ")
                if compname not in os:
                        print("os name not found")
                        continue
                compsname = os[compname]
                print("OS type = " + compsname)
```

**Try to use 4 spaces for indentation; 8 is a bit much. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)**